# Defining an abbreviated notation for referencing glossary entries

Tags: macros, glossaries

I have defined a command for adding a new symbol to the glossaries as follows:

```
\newcommand{\NewSymb}[4]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{
        name=#2,
        description={\nopostdesc #3}, 
        sort=#4,
        type=los,
        nonumberlist=true
    }
}
```

which can then be used for example like this:

```
\NewSymb{s:lattice}{\ensuremath{\Lambda}}{A Lattice}{lattice}
```

Now, in the text I can refer to this entry via

```
\gls[hyper=false]{s:lattice}
```

but this is a bit too long for my taste. Therefore I have defined a command via

```
\newcommand{\LA}{{\gls[hyper=false]{s:lattice}}}
```

but I was wondering if it is somehow possible to integrate this `\newcommand` into the `\NewSymb` command, such that, after executing, say

```
\NewSymb{s:lattice}{\ensuremath{\Lambda}}{A Lattice}{lattice}{LA}
```

I automatically have access to an abbreviated command `\LA`. The name of the abbreviated command would be provided as a parameter of the NewSymb command.

Comment: Please enclose your inline code with `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\NewSymb}[5]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{
        name=#2,
        description={\nopostdesc #3}, 
        sort=#4,
        type=los,
        nonumberlist=true
    }
   \newcommand#5{\gls[hyper=false]{#1}}
}

\NewSymb{s:lattice}{\ensuremath{\Lambda}}{A Lattice}{lattice}{\LA}
```

The fifth argument is the control sequence for calling `\gls`. It would be possible to express the argument without the backslash, but it's overkill.

It's possible to avoid the check made by `\newcommand` by changing it into `\def`. However it's a very risky behavior to redefine existing commands. For example, try to redefine `\fi`. An acceptable compromise might be

```
\newcommand{\NewSymb}[6][\newcommand]{
    \newglossaryentry{#2}{
        name=#3,
        description={\nopostdesc #4}, 
        sort=#5,
        type=los,
        nonumberlist=true
    }
   #1#6{\gls[hyper=false]{#2}}
}
```

after which

```
\NewSymb{s:lattice}{\ensuremath{\Lambda}}{A Lattice}{lattice}{\LA}
```

would work as before. But

```
\NewSymb[\renewcommand]{x}{y}{z}{X}{\fi}
```

would redefine `\fi`. (***DON'T*** do it!)

Comment: @Christian In order that the question doesn't remain among the unanswered ones, it's necessary to mark an answer as accepted. There's no hurry, however.

Comment: @egreg: Actually, one upvote is sufficient. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: nice to know.

Comment: I marked it as accepted. BTW is there any chance to automatically override commands that are already defined that I pass as an argument. The thing is that `\newcommand` actually does not quite work for me specifically, because sometimes I pass a command name that is already in use. I found `\providecommand` which works, but then I have to manually use `\renewcommand` after calling `\NewSymb` anyway. Is there something like \deletecommand that I can insert prior to `\newcommand`?

Comment: @Christian: It's very dangerous to automatically redefine commands. See the edited answer.

Comment: @egreg: works, ty!